# Windows File Explorer Search Results Extract

Tags: windows, pdf, windows-search

So I have a several thousand PDFs spread across many folders in a network drive. And I need a single piece of text data from them. Windows Search actually lets me find them all, and actually shows me the information I'm looking for:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpfM4.png)

I just need a way to extract that application ID number into a format that I can use to look retrieve their info from my database.

I can't upload them to any websites, and windows is taunting me with showing me the info I need, but no way to make it usable.

These shows up in the "content preview" part of a File Explorer search  with the View set to Content. They may also have to be indexed, I tried making a few sample ones on my C: drive but it just lists the file path and not what content it's found in the search.

Comment: If you select all results (Ctrl-A) and right-mouse drag them into a new folder, selecting to *make a shortcut* there, can you extract that info using those shortcuts, all in one spot? (If there are many items, test a few before selecting all, though.)

Comment: You're linked screenshot is so cropped it's hard to tell where it's coming from. Is that a column in Details view. Is it the **Preview Pane**? If you're serching `Content`, the UI doesn't offer a column for the matched data, but you could access the SearchResults from a script and parse the desired data from properties not available through the UI.